# How do I set the background image size in CSS?

Tags: css, background-image, background-size

So I have css code as follows:

```css
.jumbobg {
    background: url('http://znc.mane-frame.com/static/silverleaf.png') fixed no-repeat, url('../img/banner-1008444.jpg') no-repeat, grey;
}
```

I was wondering, for the first image (silverleaf.png) - how would I set the `background-size` for that particular image, using either pixels (for silverleaf) or `auto`? I tried with `background-size` tag, but it would resize all the backgrounds defined above.

Comment: No i had two backgrounds. One is silverleaf and the other one is banner-1008444.jpg.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS3 Backgrounds - multiple background-size properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919890/css3-backgrounds-multiple-background-size-properties)

Comment: @seahorsepip, I looked over that, but I didn't understand the answer given.

Comment: it's the same code just the other way around, he wanted only to resize the second instead of the first image.

Comment: @seahorsepip Its not that, I didn't get what `cover` did, and and answer wasn't clear enough. It didn't explain the coma usage, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that you have specified two backgrounds in `background` property (separated with comma), so you have to do the same with `background-size` to get their distinct values, when you specify only one value in `background-size` it is applied for both images, to be clear:

`background-size: 50px 80px;` - this is one value

`background-size: 50px 80px, auto;` - those are two values

Use comma separator as you did in `background`, so for example this should work as you want:

```
background-size: 50px 80px, auto;
```

Comment: Read the docs. He was using it in a wrong way, It's different, when you just put a value for all backgrounds and when you specify two values separated with comma.

Comment: Perfect! Just what I need! Very detailed answer, helped me a lot! :)

Answer (score 3):

for multiple backgrounds in the way you are using (shorthand) here is the syntax:

> ```
> background: [ <bg-layer> , ]* <final-bg-layer>
>
> <bg-layer> = <bg-image> || <bg-position> [ / <bg-size> ]? || <repeat-style> || <attachment> || <box>{1,2}
>
> <final-bg-layer> = <bg-image> || <bg-position> [ / <bg-size> ]? || <repeat-style> || <attachment> || <box>{1,2} || <background-color>
> ```

so with that in mind here is an example how to set  `background-size` for the 1st background:

```css
body {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/900) repeat-x scroll 0 45px / auto 100%, url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/45) no-repeat scroll center 0 / 100% auto
}
```

Comment: OP asked for `background-size`, not `background-position`

Comment: Ok its almost 3am here I didn't read well at first,. I'll update my answer ASAP @MaciejKwas

Comment: That's *much* better +1 :) However, take under consideration that for a moment it won't work in FF sinse, as far as I know, it doesn't support `<bg-position> [ / <bg-size> ]` notation, just fyi

Comment: it supports, Im using FF, and use this in my projects for a long time ;)

Comment: Oh - I checked and they really did, sorry for confusion :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
background-image: url('http://znc.mane-frame.com/static/silverleaf.png'), url(../img/banner-1008444.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
background-position: 0 0;
background-size: 350px 350px, cover;
```